# Tilde(~) in nginx.conf for relative path

Tags: nginx, tilde-expansion

I want to use the tilde (~) to point to the `/home/user` directory as I want to have relative paths in production, but doesn't seem to work in nginx.conf file, although it works fine with `.ini` files. Also tried $HOME and $(HOME)

`location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     ~/qa/web/projects/dynamic_testbeds/uwsgi_params;
    }`

What is that I'm missing?

Comment: This seems related: http://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf

Comment: `~`, `$HOME` are for meaningless without current user. Who's homedir you want?

Comment: I want to point to whoever is loggedin. Example - `/home/rohit` if I'm logged in.